# How to prevent R to reduce decimal places from 2 to 1 after running a code in a list?

Tags: r, list, numbers, decimal, subset

I want to run a code within a list and just discovered, that R reduced the decimal places of the numbers from 2 to 1 in the column I use 'subset' in the list and rounds those with original two places up or down.
I would like R to let both decimal places or add a zero to those who only have one.
Here an example data frame:

```
set.seed(94756)

mat1 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),50, replace = TRUE),ncol = 5) 
mat1 <- as.data.frame(mat1)
colnames(mat1) <- c("C1","C2", "C3","C4", "C5")

mat2 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),50, replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
mat2 <- as.data.frame(mat2)
colnames(mat2) <- c("C1","C2", "C3","C4", "C5")

mat3 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11), 50,replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
mat3 <- as.data.frame(mat2)
colnames(mat3) <- c("C1","C2", "C3","C4", "C5")

data <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3)

data2 <- lapply(data, subset, C4 > 10 & C4 <= 70)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the output you get and the output you want?

Comment: Following up @DaveArmstrong's comment: please edit your question to show obtained output in a *text format* rather than a screenshot/image ...

Comment: When I run this everything has two digits after the decimal

Comment: @BenG: column C4 which I subset has only one digit after the decimal

Comment: ahaa but it happens only in global environment, just found out. If I run print(data2) all digits are there. Sorry!